# How to Build a javascript interpreter For a custom made Browser?

Tags: c#, browser

I am working on my college project to build a Web Browser. I am Halfway through My Project and i came to know that WebBrowsers need javascript interpreters to Display latest websites.I am using c# language in Visual studio 2012. It Still Displays Some of the Basic Webpages but Doesn't Displays latest updated webpages like Google maps. I tried to suppress the error but doesn't help in other high end web pages. So how can i build a javascript  interpreter and install it in my web browser.

[image: error message image]

---

Code I used to suppress the error

```
c# getCurrentBrowser().ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
```

Comment: Just to clarify: The browser clearly does have a JavaScript interpreter - otherwise you couldn't be getting JavaScript errors. It just can't handle the pages you're visiting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that, you code is using the IE browser of your windows. IE often have incompatibilities. Try doing some research and inject a proper browser like chromium or gecko.

Look at [this package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.WinForms/)